# Can functions access their name?

Tags: elisp, functions

In C there is the magic variable `__func__` that holds the current function name. In Bash, there is an array `FUNCNAME` holding the names of all functions in the calling stack !!!

Is there a similar thing in Emacs Lisp? Or any simple way for a function to have access to its name?

I have not found any answer in the Emacs Lisp manual (chapter 12 on Functions or index of variables and functions and ..)

Comment: What do you actually need that for?

Comment: It's not exactly a magic variable -- it's a pre-processor definition inserted by *some* compilers.

Comment: @SeanAllred: __FUNCTION__ is non standard, __func__ exists in C99 / C++11. Similar __LINE__ and __FILE__ are standard.

Comment: @user227: Q: How often have you seen or written code like (defun foo () ... (message "debug in foo") ...)? Q: how often have you seen (defun foo () ... (message "debug in bar") ...) because somebody cut and pasted or change the name of a function? A: things like __func__, __FILE__, and __LINE__ are pretty much a BKM  in language design by now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Updated answer with expansion time lookup:

I said in my original answer that there may be a way to do this at expansion/compile time instead of run time to give better performance and I finally implemented that today while working on my answer for this question: [How can I determine which function was called interactively in the stack?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-can-i-determine-which-function-was-called-interactively-in-the-stack/7405#7405)

Here is a function that yields all current backtrace frames

```lisp
(defun call-stack ()
  "Return the current call stack frames."
  (let ((frames)
        (frame)
        (index 5))
    (while (setq frame (backtrace-frame index))
      (push frame frames)
      (incf index))
    (remove-if-not 'car frames)))
```

Using that in a macro we can look up the expansion stack to see what function definition is being expanded at the time and put that value right in the code.

Here is the function to do the expansion:

```lisp
(defmacro compile-time-function-name ()
  "Get the name of calling function at expansion time."
  (symbol-name
   (cadadr
    (third
     (find-if (lambda (frame) (ignore-errors (equal (car (third frame)) 'defalias)))
              (reverse (call-stack)))))))
```

Here it is in action.

```lisp
(defun my-test-function ()
  (message "This function is named '%s'" (compile-time-function-name)))

(symbol-function 'my-test-function)
;; you can see the function body contains the name, not a lookup
(lambda nil (message "This function is named '%s'" "my-test-function"))

(my-test-function)
;; results in:
"This function is named 'my-test-function'"
```

---

### Original Answer:

You can use `backtrace-frame` to look up the stack until you see frame that represents a direct function call and get the name from that.

```lisp
(defun get-current-func-name ()
  "Get the symbol of the function this function is called from."
  ;; 5 is the magic number that makes us look 
  ;; above this function
  (let* ((index 5)
         (frame (backtrace-frame index)))
    ;; from what I can tell, top level function call frames
    ;; start with t and the second value is the symbol of the function
    (while (not (equal t (first frame)))
      (setq frame (backtrace-frame (incf index))))
    (second frame)))

(defun my-function ()
  ;; here's the call inside my-function
  (when t (progn (or (and (get-current-func-name))))))

(defun my-other-function ()
  ;; we should expect the return value of this function
  ;; to be the return value of my-function which is the
  ;; symbol my-function
  (my-function))

(my-other-function) ;; => 'my-function
```

Here I am doing the function name lookup at runtime though it is probably possible to implement this at a macro that expands directly into the function symbol which would be more performant for repeat calls and compiled elisp.

I found this information while trying to write a sort of function call logger for elisp which can be found here in it's incomplete form, but it might be useful to you. https://github.com/jordonbiondo/call-log

Comment: Thanks for the code. This solves my problem and I'll accept it in a few days unless someone give us the *some sort of "current-function-name" variable that is part of the debugger* you hint at.

Comment: By the way, it does not seem to work when a `defun` is enclosed by `eval-and-compile`, i.e. it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 8):

For interactive functions, i.e., commands, you can use the variable `this-command`, or safer, `real-this-command`. The difference being that when you write your own functions, you can explicitly change the value of `this-command`. Mostly this is done to play tricks with `last-command` related to repeating commands. You shouldn't (can't?) do this with `real-this-command`. It will always be the name of the current command.

I'm not aware of an equivalent for non-interactive functions.

Comment: It's important to note that `this-command` and `real-last-command` are not at all like `__func__`. For instance if command A calls command B which prints `this-command` it will print command A, not B, also this does not work at all for functions.

Comment: @JordonBiondo Agreed. I did note that it doesn't work for functions. phs didn't give us his context, so I guessed that this might be good enough for his application. Your answer is more robust, no question.